# "Debug or Profile APK" option not shown in Android Studio menus

Tags: android-studio, debugging, apk, profile

I am using Android Studio 3.2.1 and I want to profile a pre-built APK with, but "Debug or Profile" option is not visible in my file menu and anywhere else! Is it a plugin that should be installed separately?

Comment: did you try this https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/#enable-debug

Comment: Yes I've read this doc, Installing LLDB didn't help me!

Comment: debuggable true? is this added?

Comment: The problem is my android studio, "Debug or Profile apk" option is gone

Comment: @MaximePeloquin This question was asked first. (This was asked 6 months ago, the other 1 month ago).

Comment: @SnakeException, yes but the linked question has answers and this one doesn't. See meta post here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha/147651#147651

Comment: @MaximePeloquin Fair enough.